# Configure simple named DNS server

Tags: bind, internal-dns, named-conf

for a test setup of a software application (with apps, specific hardware and so on) i need to route an public existing domain to an internal server instead of the public server. I would do this with a network, special configured for this test setup. The server with the software, apps and special hardware are in this network. I would rout the requests to the concerning domain to the internal server with a simple DNS server

This DNS server needs to:
route all requests to the domain *.internal.net to 192.168.1.200
resolve all other domain names via an external DNS server, e.g. 8.8.8.8

I have some experience with CentOS (our software in running on a CentOS server) so i decided to setup the DNS server on Centos 7. After some Googling i found that i can set up the DNS server under CentOS with named.

After installing named, i changed the /etc/named.conf file as described in one of the tutorials i found via Google. I added at the bottom:

```
zone "." IN {
    type master;
    file "internal.net";
    allow-update { none; };
};
```

Te rest of the file is not changed. I also created a file internal.net in /var/named with the following content:

```
$TTL 3200
@       IN      SOA     parkzz.net    (
    2016050204      ; serial
    3600            ; refresh
    900             ; retry
    604800          ; expire
    86400           ; nxdomain ttl
)

@                 IN      NS      internal.net
internal.net      IN      A       192.168.1.200
www.internal.net  IN      A       192.168.1.200
*.internal.net    IN      A       192.168.1.200
```

After executing 'service named restart' and configuring the ip of the DNS server into my windows, i noticed that the domain internal.net was not routed to my "internal" web server.

I also found on the internet that the part (what is inside the /etc/named.conf by default)

```
 zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
 };
```

is used to resolve "unknown" domains over an external DNS server. But i can also not visit other websites like google.nl after i set my DNS IP to the IP of my own DNS server.

What i'm doing wrong? i mean i really need some small basics but can not get it working at all.

Comment: Can't you just configure entries in your `hosts` files on the affected machines? Setting up a complete DNS server seems like overkill for this.

Comment: unfortunately not, i need to connect 2 smartphones (iOS and Android) and some custom hardware to the same network as they make requests to x.internal.net 

The host file does also not support a wildcard (*.internal.net) what is used by our software.

For an external audit we need to simulate the real environment 1 to 1 in a test setting. This means we cannot change the API URL's in the software else i would have done that.

Thanks for your idea anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the named.ca file is populated and up to date. Get a current one by FTP using

`wget --user=ftp --password=ftp ftp://ftp.rs.internic.net/domain/db.cache -O /etc/named/named.ca`

BIND's logging is usually good by default although you don't mention what OS you are using but it does normally show any configuration errors. A common issue is that it's configured to listen on localhost, which I think is the default so you may need it to listen on an interface.

You can test from your desktop with nslookup in a cmd window with `nslookup -v internal.net 192.168.1.200` which should show if your server is responding at all.

You could also use a forwarding DNS server instead so you would need to configure forwarders in your BIND configuration. [This guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-caching-or-forwarding-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) may help.

Comment: You do not need forwarder AND hints